# why are my created files hidden?

Tags: python, command-line, urllib

So I am using [urllib's urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to download images from the web. Here is my code:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
count = 1
folder = '/Users/name/Desktop/folder/'
for src in urls:
    file_name = folder + str(count) + '.png'
    urlretrieve(src,file_name)
```

So when I open finder, none of the images are in that folder, but when I run `ls /users/name/Desktop/folder/` in terminal, all of the images are listed!

**Why is this happening, and how can I set it so that it does not?**

note: it also does the same thing if I don't specify folder and I try and put the image in the current director. Also, **the same code was working fine last week**. So I really don't understand what is going on...

here is output from the `ls` command:

```
001.png             034.png             067.png             100.png
002.png             035.png             068.png             101.png
003.png             036.png             069.png             102.png
004.png             037.png             070.png             103.png
005.png             038.png             071.png             104.png
006.png             039.png             072.png             105.png
007.png             040.png             073.png             106.png
008.png             041.png             074.png             107.png
009.png             042.png             075.png             108.png
010.png             043.png             076.png             109.png
011.png             044.png             077.png             110.png
012.png             045.png             078.png             111.png
013.png             046.png             079.png             112.png
014.png             047.png             080.png             113.png
015.png             048.png             081.png             114.png
016.png             049.png             082.png             115.png
017.png             050.png             083.png             116.png
018.png             051.png             084.png             117.png
019.png             052.png             085.png             DOCUMENTATION
020.png             053.png             086.png             DOCUMENTATION.txt
021.png             054.png             087.png             PEONY_2012-02-03_MOVIE.mov
022.png             055.png             088.png             creator_script.py
023.png             056.png             089.png             multi_maps.py
024.png             057.png             090.png             multi_maps.pyc
025.png             058.png             091.png             open_source_maps.py
026.png             059.png             092.png             readme.txt
027.png             060.png             093.png             test_movie.mov
028.png             061.png             094.png             test_movie2.mov
029.png             062.png             095.png             test_movie3.mov
030.png             063.png             096.png             test_movie4.mov
031.png             064.png             097.png             test_movie5.mov
032.png             065.png             098.png             test_movie6.mov
033.png             066.png             099.png             test_movie7.mov
```

And in finder it displays none of the PNG files

here is the `ls -l` for the directory suggested by @Badaro:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180203 Jun  5 21:19 001.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180318 Jun  5 21:19 002.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180339 Jun  5 21:19 003.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180262 Jun  5 21:19 004.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180336 Jun  5 21:19 005.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180353 Jun  5 21:19 006.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180272 Jun  5 21:19 007.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180353 Jun  5 21:19 008.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180353 Jun  5 21:19 009.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179645 Jun  5 21:19 010.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179473 Jun  5 21:19 011.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180199 Jun  5 21:20 012.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180373 Jun  5 21:20 013.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180304 Jun  5 21:20 014.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180371 Jun  5 21:20 015.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180387 Jun  5 21:20 016.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180321 Jun  5 21:20 017.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180387 Jun  5 21:20 018.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180397 Jun  5 21:20 019.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180492 Jun  5 21:20 020.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180392 Jun  5 21:20 021.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180343 Jun  5 21:20 022.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180503 Jun  5 21:20 023.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180461 Jun  5 21:20 024.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180514 Jun  5 21:20 025.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180524 Jun  5 21:21 026.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180457 Jun  5 21:21 027.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180527 Jun  5 21:21 028.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180520 Jun  5 21:21 029.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180498 Jun  5 21:21 030.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180403 Jun  5 21:21 031.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180502 Jun  5 21:21 032.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180364 Jun  5 21:21 033.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180479 Jun  5 21:21 034.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180521 Jun  5 21:21 035.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180536 Jun  5 21:21 036.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180475 Jun  5 21:21 037.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180542 Jun  5 21:21 038.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180530 Jun  5 21:21 039.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180450 Jun  5 21:21 040.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180337 Jun  5 21:22 041.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180459 Jun  5 21:22 042.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180472 Jun  5 21:22 043.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180287 Jun  5 21:22 044.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180479 Jun  5 21:22 045.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180483 Jun  5 21:22 046.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180406 Jun  5 21:22 047.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180480 Jun  5 21:22 048.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180493 Jun  5 21:22 049.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180495 Jun  5 21:22 050.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180402 Jun  5 21:22 051.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180331 Jun  5 21:22 052.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179678 Jun  5 21:22 053.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180123 Jun  5 21:22 054.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179621 Jun  5 21:22 055.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180062 Jun  5 21:22 056.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179437 Jun  5 21:22 057.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179831 Jun  5 21:22 058.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179202 Jun  5 21:22 059.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179311 Jun  5 21:22 060.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180606 Jun  5 21:22 061.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180717 Jun  5 21:22 062.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180733 Jun  5 21:23 063.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180675 Jun  5 21:23 064.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180736 Jun  5 21:23 065.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180554 Jun  5 21:23 066.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180677 Jun  5 21:23 067.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180741 Jun  5 21:23 068.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180756 Jun  5 21:23 069.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180648 Jun  5 21:23 070.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180545 Jun  5 21:23 071.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180650 Jun  5 21:23 072.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180663 Jun  5 21:23 073.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180600 Jun  5 21:23 074.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180662 Jun  5 21:23 075.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180682 Jun  5 21:23 076.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180499 Jun  5 21:23 077.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180679 Jun  5 21:23 078.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180683 Jun  5 21:23 079.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180710 Jun  5 21:23 080.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180611 Jun  5 21:23 081.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181368 Jun  5 21:23 082.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181395 Jun  5 21:23 083.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181324 Jun  5 21:23 084.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181378 Jun  5 21:23 085.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181393 Jun  5 21:24 086.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181329 Jun  5 21:24 087.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  181222 Jun  5 21:24 088.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180521 Jun  5 21:24 089.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180488 Jun  5 21:24 090.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180401 Jun  5 21:24 091.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180484 Jun  5 21:24 092.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180500 Jun  5 21:24 093.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180459 Jun  5 21:24 094.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180516 Jun  5 21:24 095.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180528 Jun  5 21:24 096.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180459 Jun  5 21:24 097.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180528 Jun  5 21:24 098.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180342 Jun  5 21:24 099.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  178802 Jun  5 21:24 100.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179348 Jun  5 21:24 101.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179312 Jun  5 21:24 102.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179303 Jun  5 21:24 103.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179526 Jun  5 21:24 104.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179750 Jun  5 21:24 105.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179809 Jun  5 21:24 106.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180570 Jun  5 21:24 107.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180100 Jun  5 21:24 108.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180000 Jun  5 21:24 109.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180219 Jun  5 21:25 110.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179745 Jun  5 21:25 111.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180293 Jun  5 21:25 112.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180304 Jun  5 21:25 113.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180268 Jun  5 21:25 114.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  180335 Jun  5 21:25 115.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179942 Jun  5 21:25 116.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  179897 Jun  5 21:25 117.png
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff    2101 Jun  3 14:07 DOCUMENTATION
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff    2101 Jun  3 14:07 DOCUMENTATION.txt
-rw-------@ 1 ryansaxe  staff  208239 May 28 19:09 PEONY_2012-02-03_MOVIE.mov
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff    7032 May 28 19:04 creator_script.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff   11604 Jun  5 21:18 multi_maps.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff   11590 Jun  5 14:50 multi_maps.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff    8349 Jun  4 17:18 open_source_maps.py
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff    1109 Jun  3 13:48 readme.txt
-rw-------@ 1 ryansaxe  staff   86295 Jun  4 17:52 test_movie.mov
-rw-------@ 1 ryansaxe  staff   87045 Jun  4 18:39 test_movie2.mov
-rw-------@ 1 ryansaxe  staff   28223 Jun  5 12:39 test_movie3.mov
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ryansaxe  staff   82172 Jun  5 11:47 test_movie4.mov
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ryansaxe  staff  242824 Jun  5 12:33 test_movie5.mov
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ryansaxe  staff  284938 Jun  5 12:40 test_movie6.mov
-rw-r--r--  1 ryansaxe  staff  260264 Jun  5 21:25 test_movie7.mov
```

note: earlier today I created test_movie through test_movie6. They were all originally invisible just like the png files, but I can see them in finder now! I cannot see test_movie7, which I just generated now using the same process with downloading the images.

Comment: I believe this question shall be moved to apple.stackexchange.com (which is not in the offtopic list for flagging...)

Comment: Can you add the output from the ls command?

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question to include that

Comment: "the same code was working fine last week" — Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I have relaunched finder and restarted my computer, both were unsuccessful.

Comment: Add the output of `ls -l` command, so we can see more details.

Comment: I added it. Let me know if you see anything odd about it

Comment: well, in your `ls` commands I can see no patterns matching your bugs. What exact version/build of OSX are you running? Maybe that'd be a bug. Try running an alternative finder application like pathfinder.app to see if it behaves the same way as finder.app (to see if it's a finder bug). Also if you got another computer with OSX, try running your script over it.

Comment: @zmo and @RyanSaxe asked for a `xattr -l`. Do it.  I'm not a Mac user, but I know that the files can have additional permissions. Maybe a file needs specific settings to show up on Finder.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're using macosx, and there the path is `/Users/name/Desktop/folder/` with a capital `U` for `Users`. I'm not sure if urlretrieve() would create a new full path, and I find it weird that it would hove the rights to do so, and usually OSX' filesystem is case insensitive (unless you told it not to), but that would explain your situation.

Comment: If that is the case then why do the images go to the folder? they are just hidden in finder...I see them there when I use `ls` on the directory

Comment: can you try to run in commandline `open /users/name/Desktop/folder`? and tell if then you can see all your images?

Comment: it does not have the images. oddly enough when I go to save a script to that folder in sublimetext2, all of them are there...

Comment: then I see two possibilities, either this is a bug in the Finder, which I never encountered (but I don't use Lion/Mountain Lion), or there is some xattr magic happening. Maybe you can run `xattr -l .` and `xattr -l *`.

Comment: also, if those files are really hidden, you can try `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` and relaunch the finder to show all hidden files.

Comment: what should `xattr -l` be returning to help me find out what is wrong?

Comment: well, to know whether there are some resources within, and if there are, what kind of resource forks, and if there are funky things in the resource forks. Did you notice anything uncommon in those files?

Comment: about xattr -l, you could look for weird patterns for those files compared to other files in your system. And you could try removing the resource forks for those files, iirc it can be done with `rm 042.png/rsrc`, or using another xattr option.